# how to stream audio and video files, but use any media player on Windows (without using Windows file sharing)

Tags: windows, media

I want to access and play media files on machine S (Windows XP) from machine C (Windows XP). Using Windows File Sharing ("share this folder" stuff), if it works, I would share the folder containing media files on machine S, and I would be able to play media files, sitting in front of C, using any media player I want. Windows somehow ensures that the remote files behave like local files.

But Windows file sharing won't work for me, is there any alternative?

If two machines were both Linux, I would install an SSH server on S and use Nautilus from C to  access and play media files.

The reason why I can't use Windows file sharing is, my campus use two different subnets, I have S and C on different subnets and it seems that the firewall governing the whole network in campus doesn't allow file sharing between different subnets. I tried changing Windows Firewall settings on S to allow C in, it still wouldn't work, so it must be the other firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a [VPN](http://www.howstuffworks.com/vpn.htm) with something like [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net) (semi-permanent, flexible, more difficult to configure) or [Hamachi/LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/) (less flexible, start up the program and log in to connect the vpn, very easy to set up).

Comment: I'm using Hamachi now. One thing that I found helps performance is disabling compression (implying a third person can see the traffic, which can be bad).

Answer (score 0):

I would still use SSH. You could check out [SSH for Windows](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/). Another option would be for you to set up a web server on machine S. It's not too difficult to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should really use set up a webserver for yourself.

If you want to stream, [vlc does it](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Stream_a_File), but I think you have to do it to individual files.

As for the webserver:
You have a few (I center on the small and lightweight):

- [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/download/)
- [nanoweb](http://nanoweb.si.kz/downloads/dist/)
- [uniformserver](http://www.uniformserver.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using SSH port forwarding for SMB.
According to [a question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/36100/port-forwarding-for-samba), this should be possible.

You'd have to install a SSH server on S and for example use [Putty on C for the port forwarding](http://www.cs.uu.nl/technical/services/ssh/putty/puttyfw.html).

Answer (score 0):

Most video players support [UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play). I suggest to setup [UPnP server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPnP_AV_MediaServers). So You will be able to stream your media but also browser them.

VLC suggested by Krazy_Kaos has web gui and remote telnet based cli, so there is option for VOD.

Comment: Linux file browsers (for example Nautilus) manage to make remote files over ssh behave like local files, but Windows Explorer doesn't seem to do that.